# Split string after each n chars using Regex with condition, C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I need to split string with new line if its length is more than 'n' chars. And after each 'n'th char there should be a new line.

I've written the code that works fine with this condition:

```
string text = "11+222+333+44444+555555+6666666";
var regex = new Regex(@".{"+n+"}");
text = regex.Replace(text, "$&" + "\r\n"); //result
```

However there's one more requirement. Assuming that the string always has a format like `digit` and `plus` (no '+' at the beggining and the end) the string should still be splitted with new line after 'n' char but it cannot split the digit. I.e. the output cannot be like this (n=15):

```
11+222+333+444
4+555555+66666
6
```

Instead it should split so that digits stay undivided and line length do not exceed n:

```
11+222+333
4444+555555
+666666
```

Also, if the line is splitted, it should not contain `'+'` neigher in the beggining nor the end. Final output:

```
11+222+333
4444+555555
666666
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string text = "11+222+333+44444+555555+6666666";
var regex = new Regex(@"(.{1," + n + @"})(\+|$)");
text = regex.Replace(text, "$1" + "\r\n"); //result
```

You try to match 1...n characters (`,{1,n}`). You put it in the first capture group. Then you have another capture group, that can be a `+` or the end of the string (`$`). When you replace, you keep the text of the first capture group (the one with the digits) (`$1`) but remove the second capture group (note that the end of the string can't be really removed)

Note that there is a funny side-effect, that is good. If you have (for example) n = 3, you'll get

```
11+222
333
44444
555555
6666666
```

that is ok... It is a best effor to keep the digits together. What happens is that the regex isn't "anchored" to anything to the left, so when it seees `4444+555555` in the end it matches 4**444+**, and replaces only that part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your output has lines with length exceeding 'n'

Comment: Works perfect :) I didn't get your point about side-effect, it works just fine with n=3.

Comment: @GyuzalR It means that if you have a `11111111111+2` you'll get `11111111111\r\n2`

Comment: I guess you mean if the length of the 1st digit exceeds n, but regex handles it :) and this case can be excluded

Answer (score 1):

Regex sounds like a bit of overkill, and will be difficult for non-expert Regex users to maintain. I would recommend some code like the following (this is air-code; in other words I just typing it in here):

```
// container of final strings
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
// original string
string original = "11+222+333+44444+555555+6666666";
// max length of new string
int n = 12;
// split to number parts
string[] numbers = original.Split("+");
// current output string
string current = ""
foreach (string number in numbers)
{
    if ((number.Length + current.Length) >= n)
    {
        // can't add this one to current so store current and start new one
        strings.Add(current);
        current = number;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(current)
        {
            current = current + "+" + number;
        }
        else
        {
            current = number;
        }
    }
}
// at end, add the final current if not empty
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(current))
{
    strings.Add(current);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, anyways, hope you, guys, had some fun :)